# RAID 1 Drives Failed status after Windows 10 rebuild (Intel to AMD)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, raid

About a year ago, I setup a RAID 1 - two drives mirroring each other on my PC running Intel CPU and Windows 10. I configured it in Disk Management.

A few days ago, I rebuilt it with an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU. When I booted up, my RAID was up and running without issue.

As a result of my new hardware my PC was crashing a couple of times per day forcing a hard reset. This caused the mirrored drives to resync which takes the best part of a day. So I ended up in a cycle of resyncing and crashing before it was complete. So my clean reinstall was from the point of unsync'd drives.

When I then did a clean reinstall of Windows 10 I disconnected the RAID drives in case I accidentally formatted them.

However when I now go into Disk Management with the new build, I see all the mirrored drives as Failed.

I have been searching online for solutions but to no avail. AOMEI Partition Assistant Server and EaseUS Partition Magic don't recognise them as they are Dynamic Disks.

The interesting part is that I could still seem them when I rebuilt the machine with new hardware, but has caused an issue when reinstalling Windows. 
[image: d]

Comment: I assume at no point, was a proper backup created, and the data on the raid doesn’t exist anywhere else?  You might have to send it to data recovery company who will have the tools to rebuild the array.

Comment: Sorry I should have confirmed. I have a full back of everything on an external drive, but given he volumes of data if I can recover that would be better and quicker rather than wiping the disks and copying from backup. I'm currently running TeskDisk to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

So after running TestkDisk for the best part of a day, it was able to recover the partitions. It didn't recover them as mirroed ones, but if I didn't have a backup I could have backed them up then.

I then broke the mirror between the disks and deleted all partitions and re-created them.